# Why do GPCRs pass exactly 7 times through the cell membrane?

Tags: biochemistry, receptor

7-transmembrane domain receptors or GPCRs are one of the most common receptors in biology.
They can be found in eukaryotic cells.

What is the significance of the number 7 here: why does it pass exactly 7 times through the cell membrane? What is so good about having it pass 7 times through it?

I can't find literature which goes deeper into this issue.

Comment: The Goldilocks effect? The magic number? There is no obvious functional reason, the structure works, but we don't know that some other would not have so any argument is circular and futile. The thing that interests experimental scientists, and can be answered by experiments, is how the binding of a hormone to the receptor transmits a signal into the cell. The details may be complex, but science seldom his simple answers, and you should be wary of people would provide them.